# Mongoose collection creates its own database, despite mongoose being connection to the desired data base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am connecting to my desired database, as follows:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/TestDB", cbFunction);
```

I define my schema as follows:

```
let model = mongoose.model('MySchema', sampleSchema);
```

But when I save a new model, it creates its own database "**myschema**" and adds the collection "**myschema**" to that DB, instead of saving it in "**TestDB**"

**EDIT:**
while printing `mongoose.connection` on the console, I got the following as part of the response:

> databaseName: accomodations

Quite strange?
Should not it be **TestDB**?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect like this

```
// your model
let model = mongoose.model('MySchema', sampleSchema);

//data base connection
var db = 'mongodb://localhost/TestDB';
mongoose.connect(db);

//connecting database
var database = mongoose.connection;
database.on('open', function () {
    console.log("database is connected");
});
```